# Creating a cached image server on ArcGIS with EPSG:4326 projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, tiles

I need to create a cached image service for development reasons which doesn't use the ArcGIS Online or Google Maps projection (EPSG:3857). It should use the EPSG:4326 projection.
I couldn't find anywhere on ArcMap to configure it. The Esri documentation suggests to use their tool to export the required XML from an existing cached map service but I don't have one.

It's important to note that I did succeed in publishing an EPSG:4326 image service to my enterprise server but when I attempt to create a cache, it wants me to add tiling schemes manually. Even when I do that, it doesn't cache.
What am I doing wrong?

Bottom Line: How do I publish a cached Image Service on ArcGIS with the EPSG:4326 projection?

P.S. On-the-fly transformation to EPSG:4326 from EPSG:3857 could also work for me. Anyone knows if that's possible? Some query string perhaps?

Comment: No, you don't want on-the-fly reprojection of a basemap; that defeats the purpose of caching. Besides, we have a One question per Question policy, so you shouldn't add a question in a postscript. Instead, focus the question on the exact steps you took, and a description of what "it doesnt't cache" means. It might help to write down the scale levels of the cache you're trying to emulate, and it might help to make a Web Mercator cache in standard format once to make sure the right services are available. The first time I tried a WGS84 cache it failed, no problems the other 10,000 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can publish imagery in any projection you want. Just make sure the rasters and dataframe are in the right projection.  Then when you are creating the service you will have to make sure you don't pick the Bing Google AGOL tiling scheme.  That will override your coordinate system and place the imagery in EPSG:3857.

So you will have to generate your own tiling scheme.  To do that us the Generate tile cache Tiling Scheme tool  it will create that XMl you can use to specify your tiling scheme.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-tile-cache-tiling-scheme.htm

make sure you select build cache automatically when you upload them.  But it could take a while depending on how many tiles you are generating.
[image]

you can also check the cache status by connecting to your GIS server in ArcCatalog.  Right click the feature service and use Check Cache Status to see if your tiles are being created or were created.  You can also manage them from there.

[image]

Here is a great vid from esri about building your own cache which you can build on your local computer and upload that package, great for saving credits in AGOL.

https://youtu.be/1ZT8hUXQsms

here are the local zoom levels that match with standard AGOL zoom levels if that helps you as well, I use these for tile caches.

```
288895.277144
144447.638572
72223.819286
36111.909643
18055.954822
9027.977411
4513.988705
2256.994353
1178.497176
282.124294
141.062147
70.531074
```